# How to call function on controller with Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an angular 1.5 typescript based app using angular material.

How can I call a function in my controller from a Dialog ?

In my example it's this.callBack() i would like to call when the user has confirmed

Code snippet

```
 public delete(condition: ModelModule.Condition): void {
        var confirm = this.$mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('delete condition!')
            .textContent('are you sure ?')
            .ariaLabel('delete')
            .ok('Ok')
            .cancel('Cancel');

        this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(answer) {
             console.log("You decided to delete "+answer)
        // how to call this function on my controller ???              
        this.callBack()

        }, function() {
            console.log("You decided cancel")
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem here? To me it seems like it would work fine with the code you posted

Comment: it fails with this: angular.js:14110 TypeError: Cannot read property 'callBack' of undefined

Comment: I found a solution my self. Start the function call with copying 'this' to your own locale variable // copy to variable otherwise calls to other function is not possible
            var that = this;
           ... rest of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` refers to the `function` and not your controller. Don't use a `function` in Typescript, use an arrow function instead, it won't create a new this-context.

```
public delete(condition: ModelModule.Condition): void {
    var confirm = this.$mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('delete condition!')
        .textContent('are you sure ?')
        .ariaLabel('delete')
        .ok('Ok')
        .cancel('Cancel');

    this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then((answer) => {
         console.log("You decided to delete " + answer);
         this.callBack();
    }, () => {
        console.log("You decided cancel");
    });
}
```

[this in Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript)